# Winding number of SSH model 3

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, topological-phase

SSH model can be written as
$$H=-\sum_n\big[Jc_n^\dagger d_n + J'd_n^\dagger c_{n+1}\big]+h.c.$$
in Fourier space
$$H(k)=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_k^\dagger && d_{k}^\dagger
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 && -Je^{ik}-J'e^{-ik}\\
-Je^{-ik}-J'e^{ik} && 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_k \\ d_{k}
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$
$$h(k)=h_1\sigma_1+h_2\sigma_2+h_3\sigma_3$$
with $h_1=-(J+J')\cos{k}$,$h_2=-(J-J')\sin{k}$ and $h_3=0$

Winding number is defined as:
$$\nu=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi dk \frac{h_1\partial_kh_2-h_2\partial_kh_1}{h_1^2+h_2^2}$$

**Question:**

It is known that winding number is $1$ for $J'>J$ and $0$ for $J>J'$ but when I calculated using above equation I found $-1$ and $1$ respectively. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is slightly different from: [Asboth](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02295.pdf), where in Chapter 1 they cover the winding number of the SSH model. You can look there for help. But I think I know the answer to your problem.

I believe your fourier transformation is incorrect. It does not agree with what is found in Asboth on page 4. The thing is that the on-site potential term
$$Jc_n^\dagger d_n$$
should not produce an exponential when you Fourier transform. Therefore I think that your Bloch Hamiltonian $h(k)$ whould look like this
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & -J-J'e^{-ik}\\
-J-J'e^{ik} & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Try calcuating the winding number with this matrix and see if you get the right answer.

Comment: @LuqmanSaleem I don't really understand what you mean, maybe you can expand. At any rate, if you insist that your $h(k)$ matrix is correct then answer me this. Does $n$ label different unit cells?